# Cant install yarn on ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu

```
will@LAPTOP-TB5IKDQ5:~$ npm install --global yarn
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/will/.npm/_logs/2022-07-25T03_31_26_158Z-debug.log
```

does anyone know how to fix this

Comment: Did you read the error message? You don't have permissions to install globally. Run with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

run:

```js
ls -l
```

This will list the directories and owners of the directories
Now run:

```js
sudo chown <user_id> <folder>
```

To get your username, run whoami
Replace '' with the folder that you do not have permissions for. This should work just fine.